# Editing object with EF 4.0 issue navigation properties not updated

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `logEvent` table and a many to many table called `logEventContact`.

my `logEventContact` looks like this :

```
LogEventID ContactID
1           2     
1           3     
12          2
```

In my edmx file, my `logEvent` table have `Contacts` as a navigation property. EF does not create an entity table `logEventContact`.

My `editLogEvent()` function looks like this:

```
public bool EditLogEvent(LogEvent logEvent)
{
    var oldLogEvent = db.LogEvents
        .Include(o => o.Contacts)
        .Include(o => o.LogEventAttachments)
        .Single(o => o.LogEventID == logEvent.LogEventID);
    db.ApplyCurrentValues("LogEvents", logEvent);
    db.SaveChanges();

    var editedLogEvent = db.LogEvents
        .Include(o => o.Contacts)
        .Include(o => o.LogEventAttachments)
        .Single(o => o.LogEventID == logEvent.LogEventID);

    ...
}
```

My save does not apply on my `logEvents.Contacts`. My `editedLogEvent.Contacts` is still the same as the old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I make it work. The management of the many-many tables by EF is really bad...

```
public bool EditLogEvent(LogEvent logEvent, out LogEvent editedLogEvent,...){
    ...
    using (var db = new DistributorEntities()){
        var oldLogEvent = db.LogEvents
            .Include(o => o.Contacts)
            .Include(o => o.LogEventAttachments)
            .Single(o => o.LogEventID == logEvent.LogEventID);

        oldLogEvent.Contacts.Clear();

        foreach (var cont in logEvent.Contacts)
        {
            var contact = db.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ContactID == cont.ContactID);
            oldLogEvent.Contacts.Add(contact);
        }
        db.LogEvents.ApplyCurrentValues(logEvent);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var editedLogEvent = db.LogEvents
            .Include(o => o.Contacts)
            .Include(o => o.LogEventAttachments)
            .Single(o => o.LogEventID == logEvent.LogEventID);
            ...
    }
}
```